# Symfony2 custom console command appears as “not defined” upon execution

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.6

Please help, I've tried everything;

The command works well on the development server, but not on live.

Before you mark it as duplicate:

- The filename ends with `Command.php`
- The Bundle is registered
- The command is `ContainerAware`
- The command is in the `Bundle\Command` directory and in the `App\Bundle\Command` namespace

I have tried:

- clearing and warming up the cache on the server multiple times using the symfony console `php console --env=preprod cache:clear` and `php console --env=preprod cache:warmup`
- listing available commands by calling the console without extra arguments `php console --env=preprod`

Is there any other way to force symfony to re-check available commands ?

Comment: Anything in the log files?

Comment: Please add relevant source code

Comment: Do you find your command doing  `console --env=preprod`? Is it defined in a general service file or in a `services_dev.yml`?

Comment: @goto no, the command was not present there, but see my answer, and you'll realize how dumb I was :)

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:

The problem was that I connected to the remote host before deploy, and bash doesn't update symlink targets.

So the Command was not available in my current working directory.

A simple `cd ..`, `cd current` solved it.

Comment: capistrano classic :)